# SignatureDoesNotMatch error while connecting to Amazon S3 through JAVA

Tags: amazon-s3

I am getting the error as "SignatureDoesnotMatch" since last 4 hours.Please check and let me know what is missing in my code:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
s3Client.setEndpoint("***my-service-end-point");
s3Client.setRegion("my-region");
java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
long milliSeconds = expiration.getTime();
milliSeconds += 1000 * 60 * 60;
expiration.setTime(milliSeconds);
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = 
 new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(existingBucketName, keyName);
  generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET); 
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expiration);

URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
System.out.println("s3Client :" + s3Client.getBucketLocation(existingBucketName))
```

Comment: Which line results in an error? Where is `url` being used?

Comment: I created the url stuff for my testing and it is failing at the last line i.e. s3Client.getBucketLocation(existingBucketName)

Answer (score 0):

First try to integrate latest aws sdk in your code and if still doesn't work then I think you are facing this issue with signature version 4 authentication mechanism. Amazon documentation states that

**

> In the Asia Pacific (Mumbai), Asia Pacific (Seoul), EU (Frankfurt) and
>   China (Beijing) regions, Amazon S3 supports only Signature Version 4.
>   In all other regions, Amazon S3 supports both Signature Version 4 and
>   Signature Version 2.

**

Please look into these links:

- http://doatt.com/2015/01/19/aws-s3-and-the-signaturedoesnotmatch-error/
- http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAWSSDK.html
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html

I hope this will give you enough idea to solve this problem.